# Should I delete my answer when it apparently hurt someone?

Tags: discussion

I've deleted my [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8511/how-should-older-programmers-respond-when-interviewed/8609#8609).

I didn't want to hurt anyone.

I checked the FAQ again and there is nothing about that point except the fact that my answer is clearly not [constructive](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).

Should we delete or avoid posting question that can potentially hurt people feelings?

Where is the limit?

Comment: I see no problem with that example.

Comment: If people are offended by that, they're being too sensitive. Personally, I think your answer was brilliant.

Comment: I undeleted it because of Robert's comment

Comment: As their 18 yo son was leaving for war in Iraq, the parents were debating: "I think we should we tell him. No Way! - the mother replied. He is too sensitive, he will not take it well. But, he is a man, if we do not tell him now, then his comrades will make fun of him. Fvck it, I am telling" - said the father, ran back inside of the bus and yelled: "Brian! I need to tell you something important. Santa Clause does not exist."

Even if you do not find the above funny, think about this: an adult should be able to handle constructive criticism. If they cannot, then it is a major problem for them.

Comment: @Job: +1 for the funny story put *in the appropriate place* with actual context to the situation.

Answer (score 6):

I often find myself re-reading my answers just before I post them and asking myself (1) if this answers the actual question or (2) is in anyway constructive.  A bunch of times after asking these questions I've abandoned my response.

If someone is continually asking dumb questions that are closed within a few minutes of posting, my inclination would be to write something a little more critical to the poster but I try to balance my critical tone with something constructive that could help the poster build a better question the next time.

As in your case I am always tempted to write something funny as my response but that usually gets edited out by my 2 questions above.

Answer (score 2):

Pain is a necessary part of the learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer is that if you think it is hurtful to someone, it is probably not a useful answer to the question to begin with. I would say avoid posting anything that could be hurtful. This includes "funny" answers/comments. A lot of the time, what seems funny at one moment can be misconstrued and seem hurtful the next.

Comment: Funny answers often get lots of votes though...

Comment: Comedy = tragedy + distance.